# Loop - SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following table in SQL database,

```
Acct_Num           Date                Amount   Debit_Credit

001234          10/Jan/2014      56879     Credit

001234          15/Jan/2014      56879     Debit

001234          10/Feb/2014      10000    Credit

001234          09/Feb/2014       9000     Credit

001234          25/Mar/2014       19000     Credit
```

Expected output

```
Acct_no      Month        Consolidate Credit       Consolidate Debit   Balance 

001234       JAN                      56879          56879             0

001234       FEB                      19000           0                                19000
```

Question:

System should pick up month wise consolidate debit / credit separately for a complete month. User will input date  (e.g  15.01.2014 ) and system should start collecting summation of debit and credit from starting month i.e from Jan - 2014 and loop should end with current system month i.e Sep - 15

Comment: Whats did you try? post your code. Will be better to you, because we will be able to help you in a accurate way

Comment: select Acct_no ,
(select sum (amount)from XYZ where Acct_no  = '001234' and date = (select extract month from date)))Sep
from XYZ where acid = '001234'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure SQL solution including a create table statement based on your data.

Here's the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Trans
    (Acct_Num varchar2(6), Tran_date date, Amount number, Debit_Credit varchar2(6))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Trans (Acct_Num, Tran_date, Amount, Debit_Credit)
         VALUES ('001234', to_Date('10-Jan-2014','dd-mon-yyyy'), 56879, 'Credit')
    INTO Trans (Acct_Num, Tran_date, Amount, Debit_Credit)
         VALUES ('001234', to_Date('15-Jan-2014','dd-mon-yyyy'), 56879, 'Debit')
    INTO Trans (Acct_Num, Tran_date, Amount, Debit_Credit)
         VALUES ('001234', to_Date('10-Feb-2014','dd-mon-yyyy'), 10000, 'Credit')
    INTO Trans (Acct_Num, Tran_date, Amount, Debit_Credit)
         VALUES ('001234', to_Date('09-Feb-2014','dd-mon-yyyy'), 9000, 'Credit')
    INTO Trans (Acct_Num, Tran_date, Amount, Debit_Credit)
         VALUES ('001234', to_Date('25-Mar-2014','dd-mon-yyyy'), 19000, 'Credit')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

and three variants of a solution.

Option 1 pivot then aggregate:

```
with pvt as (
select *
  from trans
  pivot (sum(amount)
    FOR Debit_Credit IN ( 'Credit' AS Credit
                        , 'Debit'  AS Debit))
) 
select acct_num
     , trunc(tran_date, 'month') period_Start
     , sum(credit) consolidate_credit
     , sum(debit) consolidate_debit
     , nvl(sum(credit),0)
     - nvl(sum(debit),0) total
  from pvt
 group by acct_num
     , trunc(tran_date, 'month');
```

Option 2 preprocess the date and then let the pivot do the aggregate:

```
with dta as (
  select acct_num, trunc(tran_date, 'month') tran_date
       , amount, Debit_Credit
    from trans
)
select acct_num
     , tran_date
     , credit consolidate_credit
     , debit consolidate_debit
     , nvl(credit,0)
     - nvl(debit,0) total
  from dta
 pivot (sum(amount)
   FOR Debit_Credit IN ( 'Credit' AS Credit
                        , 'Debit'  AS Debit));
```

Option 3 Pivot and aggregate all in one:

```
select acct_num
     , trunc(tran_date, 'month')
     , sum(credit) consolidate_credit
     , sum(debit) consolidate_debit
     , nvl(sum(credit),0)
     - nvl(sum(debit),0) total
  from trans
 pivot (sum(amount)
   FOR Debit_Credit IN ( 'Credit' AS Credit
                        , 'Debit'  AS Debit))
 group by acct_num
     , trunc(tran_date, 'month');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try avoid looping in SQL. SQL is based on discrete mathematics and therefore you should always try set operations.

To solve your problem you should be grouping by your account number , date then your debit or credit type column. In your main select you should then sum your amount column and convert your date to a month value only. Be cautious when it comes to overlapping more than one year you might want to add a year column to your output.